# How would I find the product of of every third number in an array or string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

This was just a random scenario I thought up of in my head, if I had this array:

```
[3,2,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]
```

and this string:

```
'325678912'
```

what code would I write using Ruby where it would produce a of:

```
3*2*5 = 30, 6*7*8 = 336, and 9*1*2 = 18
```

and put this into an array of:

```
[30,336,18]
```

Sorry I forgot to put my code that's returning the wrong answer:

```
b = [3,2,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]


first = 0
third = first + 2
array = []
while first<b.length
  prod=1
  b[first..third].each do |x|
    prod*=x.to_i
    array<<prod
  end
  first+=2
  third = first + 2
end

print array
```

And my other piece of code for the string:

```
a = '325678912'

number = a.split('')
first = 0
third = first + 2
array = []
while first<number.length
  prod=1
  number[first..third].each do |x|
    prod*=x.to_i
    array<<prod
  end
  first+=2
  third = first + 2
end

print array
```

For both pieces of code I get this answer: [3, 6, 30, 5, 30, 210, 7, 56, 504, 9, 9, 18, 2], what I want is this: [30,336,18]

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're supposed to write the code yourself.

Comment: i like the idea of this.. but have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
[3,2,5,6,7,8,9,1,2].each_slice(3).map { |a,b,c| a*b*c }
# => [30, 336, 18]
[3,2,5,6,7,8,9,1,2].each_slice(3).map { |x| x.reduce(:*) }
# => [30, 336, 18]
```

---

Use [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chars) to convert a string into an array of single character strings. Then use above code to get the result:

```
'325678912'.chars
# => ["3", "2", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1", "2"]
'325678912'.chars.map(&:to_i)
# => [3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
'325678912'.chars.map(&:to_i).each_slice(3).map { |a,b,c| a*b*c }
# => [30, 336, 18]
```

Comment: Or `.map { |x| x.reduce(:*) }` to handle arbitrary sizes

Comment: @Stefan, Thank you for comment. I added that to the answer code.

Comment: You could use `chars` in place of `split('')`, it is more clear and probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, with comments.

```
b = [3,2,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]
first = 0
third = first + 2
array = []
while first<b.length
  prod=1
  b[first..third].each do |x|
    prod*=x.to_i  # to_i unnecessary, already integer
    array<<prod   # Ah no. Too early. move this outside the block
  end
  #Here would be fine.
  #And don't forget to reset prod to 1.
  first+=2  #3 ! not 2.
  third = first + 2
end

print array
```

Comment: Hi I made the changes that you recommended and I'm still getting the wrong answer.  This is the answer I get with your changes:[60, 504, 2].  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed the problem.  Thanks a lot for the help!  I was wondering why the "array<<prod" has to be moved outside of the block and why do I have to write "prod=1" once again but this time outside of the block?

Comment: Experiment. Comment out prod = 1 and see what happens. Move array<<prod inside the block and again see what happens.